# Hosting a WCF service using net.tcp binding in IIS 7 (unreachable from outside)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, tcp

I have developped a WCF duplex service and a Windows Winforms client communicating togeteher via a net.tcp duplex binding.

Both do communicate and work fine on my LAN, the WCF service beeing hosted on a IIS 7 on a Windows 8 workstation.

I then tried to host the WCF service on the web on a rent dedicated server running Windows server 2008 R2 with a fixed IP adress: (94.23.220.199) with IIS 7 running and .Net 4.5.2.

The WCF service has been installed on the /ScgBroadcastorService  virtual path and the net.tcp protocol has been activated. (Actually, all the IIS configuration stuff has been made exactly like on my personnal IIS on my LAN).  So the service should be reachable from the outside on the following URL: "http://94.23.220.199/ScgBroadcastorService/Service.svc".

If you access this link from your browser, you'll get a correct "ScgBroadcastorService Service" page with the two wsdl links. (These links correctly refer to the "94.23.220.199" IP address.

If one clicks on this links one correctly gets the wsdl xml document.

So since the wsdl document may be accessed from the outside, I expect the client to be able to communicate with the WCF service..

But if I launch the client, I get the following exception: (Sorry my home computer is localized in french... The root exception is "The server rejected the client credentials.")

Here is the full trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Le serveur a rejeté les informations d'identification du client. ---> System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: Le serveur a rejeté les informations d'identification du client. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: La tentative d’ouverture de session a échoué
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   à System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, ChannelBinding binding, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   à System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---

Server stack trace: 
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream stream)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Note that if I launch the client directly from the host computer, with the same client config file, the client connects and communicates perfectly !

Here is the web.config file currently installed on the server hosting the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ScgServiceLibrary.ScgBroadcastorService">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ScgServiceLibrary.IScgBroadcastorService">
          <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/94.23.220.199" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here is the client config file I've been using from the outside and from the host:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
              <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IScgBroadcastorService">
                <security mode="None"></security>
              </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://94.23.220.199/ScgBroadcastorService/Service.svc"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IScgBroadcastorService"
                contract="ScgServiceLibrary.IScgBroadcastorService" name="NetTcpBinding_IScgBroadcastorService">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/94.23.220.199" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Note that I have added the

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

line at the end of the web.config file on the server to get a service page with the IP address on the two wsdl links. Without this line the two links include the computername "ns304385" instead of the IP address and of course the wsdl cannot be got from the outside.

Thank you to help mo to solve the remaining deployment issues.. I'm now stucked and don't know what to do to allow my client to reach my WCF service hosted on the net...

Comment: Is the **net.tcp** binding (808:*) activated on the web site in IIS?  Pretty sure the _Net.Tcp Listener Adapter_ Windows serice for WPA needs to be running too

Comment: I have activated the net.tcp protocol in the advanced settings of the ScgBroadcastorService application hosted in IIS. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: And yes, the "net.tcp listener adapter" service is running.

Comment: Not quite.  Though you have "net.tcp" in **Advanced Settings.Enabled Protocols**, ultimately **net.tcp** must appear in **Bindings** on the `web site node` e.g. select _"Default web site"_; then click **Bindings...**.  Check that too thanks

Comment: Yes, I just checked this. The net.tcp protocol appears (808.*) in the Bindings settings of my Default web site...

Comment: Hmmm...is the production WS you are renting blocking port 808?

Comment: To me there seems two issues. 1. IP 94.23.220.199 is not accessible from outside. 2. ServicePrincipleName (SPN) in configuration doesn't look good.

Comment: For the 1st issue, you can check yourself that IP 94.23.220.199 is accessible from outside. Concerning the 2nd one, I agree. The SPN Identity element of the xml document is "host/ns304385" ! It refers to the computer name and not the IP address. I noticed this as well. But the question is why ?! Is that something wrong in my web.config file leading to thi suspicious SPN element ?

Comment: I've just updated the web.config file adding a identity / servicePrincipalName element in the endpoint element, setting its value to "host/94.23.220.199". Now the SPN element at the end of the wsdl document appears correct. But the exception remains when the client tries to connect to the server...

Comment: I just updated the description of the issue in the text of my post with the latest enhancements I found tonight.

First I understood why I got a CryptAndSign soap error on my home (firefox) browser. it was due to the installed Skype "Clickandcall" plugin. I deactivated it and I got the wsdl document at home too.

Secondly I noticed that some of the modifications I had made on the web.config file prevented the client to run on the host. It was due to the added address= attribute in the endpoint element. So I deleted it and the client is again working fine when launched from the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally solved the issue in the middle of the night...

I had to turn off the security of the netTcpBinding on both side.

But it was not so simple to find out how to turn it off on the server side for a contract requiring duplex communication.

Here is the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="customTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" maxConnections="10">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ScgServiceLibrary.ScgBroadcastorService">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customTcpBinding" contract="ScgServiceLibrary.IScgBroadcastorService">
          <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/94.23.220.199" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The trick was to add a customTcpBinding with the security mode set to "None" and to refer this new binding in the endpoint with the bindingConfiguration attribute.

Not sure wether all the parameters of the customTcpBinding are optimal, but they are ok for a duplex contract. (My first attempt was refused for a duplex contract)

On the client side I also had to set the security mode of the binding to "None". Here is my new config file on the client side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IScgBroadcastorService">
                    <security mode="None"></security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://94.23.220.199/ScgBroadcastorService/Service.svc"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IScgBroadcastorService"
                contract="ScgServiceLibrary.IScgBroadcastorService" name="NetTcpBinding_IScgBroadcastorService">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/94.23.220.199" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And finally my WCF Windows WinForm client works fine and communicate with my Duplex WCF Service !!!

I have to say that solving this issue was a real nightmare...

Hope this complete description of my issue will help other developpers trying to host their duplex net.Tcp binded WCF service on the net and bored with all the unexpected exception before finding the right way to modify their config files.

Good night folks ! Only three hours to sleep before returning to job... :-(

Comment: `Security mode = "none"` - isn't that risky with sending credentials over the Internet?

Comment: As I understand, setting the security mode to "none" on both client and server side means sending and checking no credentials at all.

Comment: I don't believe so.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748115/wcf-disabling-security-in-nettcpbinding-c  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734784(v=vs.110).aspx.  If you are putting credentials in the payload it will be transmitted unencrypted.

Comment: In my application (See description and test it yourself at http://94.23.220.199 if you are interested) I do not transmit any credentials. I want the client to be public and no check is necessary to authentify the users of the client app. The WCF service do not care about who is talking to him. That's not a classical Client/Server architecture. In most professionnal Client/Server systems it is obviously required to authentify that the client users really are who they pretend to be and that they are granted to access the service. That's simply not my use case.

Comment: I'm just going by this remark _"So I tried to **create an account on the server** with the **same name and password** than the account I'm using on my home computer when I try to launch the client... and... It works !!!"_ which led me to believe you were using computer (not user) authentication.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

WOW ! I just found a partial solution !

At least an explanation of why I cannot reach the WCF service from the outside !

Reading this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1551b4e1-8e15-4da2-b155-d398379809b3/the-server-has-rejected-the-client-credentials-in-wcf?forum=wcf

So I tried to create an account on the server with the same name and password than the account I'm using on my home computer when I try to launch the client... and... It works !!!

Of course you'll agree with me this is not acceptable...

I want my WCF service beeing able to accept clients connexions from user logged from anywhere on the net and using their own username/password I do not want to care !

So, the search continues on another way... How to allow WCF client connections without having to create accounts on my server ?

Stay tuned... hope will soon find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

setting security mode to "none" is not the way you should solve this because setting security to None will also remove confidentiality (encryption) and integrity (signing) of your messages.

```
<security mode="None"></security>
```

To remove authentication you can either:
1) set the security mode to message

```
<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IScgBroadcastorService">
            <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

2) or set the security mode to Transport

```
<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IScgBroadcastorService">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have to admit that I didn't try this with your code.
Just want to make sure people reading this do know that authentication and message security are not the same thing and point them in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for a duplex wcf service, hosted in a windows service on a remote machine. To make it work I had to create Inbound and Outbound rules to open the service port in Windows Firewall advanced settings. Also I've created a server user and included this code in my client:

```
this._client = new WcfService.WcfServiceClient(context);
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = user;
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = password;
```